# "Workflow can use app permissions" feature is missing

Tags: workflow, feature, app

I am using sharepoint 2013 sp1 on Windows Server 2012 R2 with workflow manager 1.0 refresh.
I want to create workflow in SharePoint Designer that will change permisions on item based on the status field. I read that I need to activate "Workflow can use app permissions" feature in site settings on my portal to enable app step in designer, but "Workflow can use app permissions" feature is missing in my site collection features. 
My other workflows that I use from SharePoint Designer are working well and they are all sharepoint 2013 based.

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those Workflow features are actually defined at the Web level under `Site Features` not `Site Collection` features.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to configure service Application Associations "WorkFlow Service Application Proxy"

1. Go to Appliaction Management - Manage web appliactions
2. Select Web Appliaction
3. Service Connections
4. Check "WorkFlow Service Application"

In this site have another solution that I really worked.
https://adminsharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/workflow-can-use-app-permissions-feature-is-not-activating/